# pct_change and log returns differ from actual values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, financial

I'm working on a dataframe with prices. I find the returns calculated arithmetic or log are different than actual return between first price value and the last. As I see it they should be the same or differ by small fractions.

```
dfset.head()
                       Open   Close    High     Low      Volume
Date_utc                                                       
2017-12-01 00:00:00  432.01  434.56  435.09  432.01  781.788110
2017-12-01 00:05:00  434.25  435.82  436.98  434.25  584.017105
2017-12-01 00:10:00  435.81  435.50  436.39  434.80  494.047392
2017-12-01 00:15:00  435.88  435.10  436.07  434.50  527.840340
2017-12-01 00:20:00  434.51  433.50  434.95  432.98  458.557971


dfset.tail()
                       Open   Close    High     Low       Volume
Date_utc                                                        
2017-12-21 23:40:00  781.41  781.01  783.46  778.12   792.433089
2017-12-21 23:45:00  779.60  784.76  784.90  778.20   657.316066
2017-12-21 23:50:00  784.83  783.42  784.90  782.22   473.108867
2017-12-21 23:55:00  783.40  786.98  787.00  782.62  1492.764405
2017-12-22 00:00:00  786.96  791.93  792.00  786.86  1745.559100
```

when calculating returns either by:

```
dfset['Close'].pct_change().sum()
0.694478597676
```

or using log returns:

```
np.log(dfset['Close'] / dfset['Close'].shift(1)).sum()
0.60013897914
```

Actual overall return which I consider to be the correct one:

```
dfset['Close'].iloc[len(dfset) - 1] / dfset['Close'].iloc[0] - 1
0.822372054492
```

Any ideas please why the arithmetic and log returns are off?

```
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 3.6.3.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Darwin
OS-release: 16.7.0
machine: x86_64
processor: i386
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: None
LOCALE: None.None

pandas: 0.21.1
pytest: 3.2.1
pip: 9.0.1
setuptools: 36.5.0.post20170921
Cython: 0.26.1
numpy: 1.13.3
scipy: 0.19.1
pyarrow: None
xarray: None
IPython: 6.1.0
sphinx: 1.6.3
patsy: 0.4.1
dateutil: 2.6.1
pytz: 2017.2
blosc: None
bottleneck: 1.2.1
tables: 3.4.2
numexpr: 2.6.2
feather: None
matplotlib: 2.1.0
openpyxl: 2.4.8
xlrd: 1.1.0
xlwt: 1.2.0
xlsxwriter: 1.0.2
lxml: 4.1.0
bs4: 4.6.0
html5lib: 0.999999999
sqlalchemy: 1.1.13
pymysql: None
psycopg2: None
jinja2: 2.9.6
s3fs: None
fastparquet: None
pandas_gbq: None
pandas_datareader: 0.5.0
None
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the 3 operations are quite different. I will take only the tail to show.

In the first place:

```
print( dfset['Close'].pct_change()) 

2017-12-21         NaN
2017-12-21    0.004801
2017-12-21   -0.001708
2017-12-21    0.004544
2017-12-22    0.006290
Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

is equivalent to do:

```
print(dfset['Close'].diff()/dfset['Close'].shift(1))

2017-12-21         NaN
2017-12-21    0.004801
2017-12-21   -0.001708
2017-12-21    0.004544
2017-12-22    0.006290
Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

So their sums are equal:

```
print((dfset['Close'].diff()/dfset['Close'].shift(1)).sum())
0.013927992282837915
```

Then I don't see the point of:

```
np.log(dfset['Close'] / dfset['Close'].shift(1))
```

being equal to the `pct_change`.

```
print(np.log(dfset['Close'] / dfset['Close'].shift(1)))

2017-12-21         NaN
2017-12-21    0.004790
2017-12-21   -0.001709
2017-12-21    0.004534
2017-12-22    0.006270
Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

The result is similar since there is no subtraction of 1 and no exponential. But this does not make it correct mathematically.

Normally, to avoid divisions I would take logarithms and subtract them and then make the exponential back. In any case, to replicate 
`pct_change`:

```
print(np.log((dfset['Close'] / dfset['Close'].shift(1))-1).apply(np.exp))
2017-12-21         NaN
2017-12-21    0.004801
2017-12-21         NaN
2017-12-21    0.004544
2017-12-22    0.006290
Name: Close, dtype: float64

print((np.log(dfset['Close'].diff()) -  np.log(dfset['Close'].shift(1))).apply(np.exp))

2017-12-21         NaN
2017-12-21    0.004801
2017-12-21         NaN
2017-12-21    0.004544
2017-12-22    0.006290
Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

In any case, using logarithm will return NaN for negative values.

So the sum of the elements is different to the use of pct_change:

```
print((np.log(dfset['Close'].diff()) -  np.log(dfset['Close'].shift(1))).apply(np.exp).sum())

0.015635520699169063
```

Finally, the last one matches the first (note, instead of using `.iloc[len(dfset) - 1]` to find the last element, you can do `.iloc[- 1]` ):

```
print(dfset['Close'].iloc[-1] / dfset['Close'].iloc[0] - 1)

0.013981895238217135
```

There is a difference in the 5th decimal between first approach and this one (of a 4% with respect to the first or in absolute terms 5.390295537921995e-05), but this differences may be due to precision issues happening in when storing floats.

**EDITED: PLOTTING THE COMPOUND INTEREST**

You explained in your comments that you want to plot the `cumsum` and that is what differs from the total change `dfset['Close'].iloc[-1] / dfset['Close'].iloc[0] - 1`.

The reason behind is that **the cumulative sum of percent change in the range of dates is not equal to the percent change between the first element and the last of the interval**.

To do so you have to use the [**compound interest**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest), **which is a formula to calculate the total increment when there are continuous changes between time steps**. This way, using the **csv** from your comment you will match the change of between the first and last day by doing:

```
print(((dfset['Close'].pct_change(axis=0)+1).cumprod()-1).iloc[-1])

0.8223720544918787

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
((dfset['Close'].pct_change(axis=0)+1).cumprod()-1).plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Mabel, thanks for the answer. My problem is that when ploting the returns with cumsum(), the graph will show, in this case a 60% increase (for pct_change) or 69% increase (for log) when in fact the increase over that period is 82%. And basically I didn't find a solution to plot the correct price increase.

Comment: It's strange. Because the results are pretty close. Could you put a reproducible example with a whole dataframe rather than the head and tail?

Comment: I uploaded the whole dataframe here: https://github.com/Octaviand21/Prices

Comment: Gotcha! I think compound interest is the guilty. Take a look now.

Comment: Great! I came to the same conclusion but I missed the cumprod() function. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Mabel!